# JS: current node in for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following HTML-Code:

```html
<input type="text" id="X1" onkeyup="xFilter()"/>
<table id="table1" class="sort">
  <tr>
    <td>X: A</td>
    <td>Y: A</td>
    <td>Z: A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X: B</td>
    <td>Y: B</td>
    <td>Z: B</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="X2" onkeyup="xFilter()"/>
<table id="table2" class="sort">
  <tr>
    <td>X: A</td>
    <td>Y: A</td>
    <td>Z: A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X: B</td>
    <td>Y: B</td>
    <td>Z: B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to filter the table column X with the function xFilter() each time. An example: I enter "A" in the first input window (id="X1") and get the first row at the first table (id="1"). The second table remains unchanged. Another example: I enter "B" in the second input window (id="X2") and get the second row at the second table (id="2"). The first table remains unchanged.

The following code works fine, but is not lean enough, because I have much tables with much filter options on my page.

```js
function XFilter1() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("X1");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table1");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}

function xFilter2() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("X2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table2");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Now when I try to merge both functions, nothing works at all and unfortunately I don't see my error. Since I just started with JavaScript, I hope for your support to learn from my mistakes. Thanks a lot already.

```js
function gpvFilter() {
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table.sortierbar");
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.gpvInput");
  for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var table = tables[i];
    var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (j = 0; j < tr.length; j++) {
      var td = tr[j].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (td) {
        var txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're using the same variable `i` in both loops. Use different variables. Also, remember to declare your variables local to the function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have corrected my code above, but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a homegrown filter that does the trick. To associate the input with the table, I put them both in the same div and used `closest('div').querySelector('table')`

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  document.querySelectorAll('.t-filter').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', e => {
  // for each of the inputs with class .t-filter...
    let trs = e.target.closest('div').querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('tr');
    // gather together all the <tr>'s in the closest table to me

    trs.forEach(tr => {
      let match = false
      // iterate through each tr. Set match to false as a default
      tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td => {
        if (td.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())) match = true;
      });
      // in this tr, iterate through all of it's td tags. If the innerText of any one of them contains the search term (case insensitive) set match to true
      if (match || e.target.value.trim() === '') tr.removeAttribute('hidden');
      else tr.setAttribute('hidden', true);
      
      // if there is a match, or we've cleared our input remove the hidden attribute from the tr
      // otherwise add the hidden attribute to the tr
    });

  }))
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class='t-filter' id="X1" />
  <table id="table1" class="sort">
    <tr>
      <td>X: A</td>
      <td>Y: A</td>
      <td>Z: A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>X: B</td>
      <td>Y: B</td>
      <td>Z: B</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class='t-filter' id="X2" />
  <table id="table2" class="sort">
    <tr>
      <td>X: A</td>
      <td>Y: A</td>
      <td>Z: A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>X: B</td>
      <td>Y: B</td>
      <td>Z: B</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works. Now I just need to understand what you did there ;)

Comment: No prob. I aded in explanations in the code if you're interested

Comment: Yes, this helps immensely - especially for me as a JS beginner ;)